# Instant email notification of replies to posts

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Where do I have to go to change the settings so that I get instant email notification of replies to posts, rather than 24 hours later?

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think this is just not possible.

Answer (score 13):

Technical questions about the site which are not TeX.SX specific, i.e. affect other stackexchange sites as well, are better asked at the general meta site https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. That's the site of the people which provide the web software for us. In fact it was already asked there: [Notify more frequently than once a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day)

The outline is: **You can't** and this is **by design**:

> If we make the email too aggressive, it's a substitute for visiting the site, and it kind of destroys the whole community aspect.
>
> [...]
>
> Email is for the less urgent stuff where you're busy and don't have time to check the site.

Answer (score 8):

You could install something like [StackApplet](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet) or you could just obsessively refresh the site every 5 minutes, like I do... (I bet I'm not the only one)